# Can I let a user customize a component's template?

Tags: ember.js

I'm making a sortable component. You could imagine a simple implementation having the following API:

```
{{sortable-list content=orderedQuestions tag='ul' itemTag='li'}}
```

But, that offers pretty limited template customization. Ideally I'd like the API to allow something like this:

```
{{#sortable-list content=orderedQuestions tag='ul'}}
  <li>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <div>Some more {{details}}</div>
  </li>
{{/sortable}}
```

where this block template gets used for each sortable item. Is this possible? I tried something like this for the component's template:

```
{{#each item in content}}
  {{#with item}}
    {{yield}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

but this doesn't work, since the block template the user passes into the component has the controller as its context.

Is what I'm after possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact thing you're trying to do is not currently possible.

Take a look [at this Github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4985) to see a lot of discussion around component use cases like this. In particular take a look at Trek's first comment.

An alternative is to break your component into multiple components:

```
{{#sortable-list content=orderedQuestions tag='ul'}}
  {{#each orderedQuestions}}
    {{#sortable-item tag='li'}}
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <div>Some more {{details}}</div>
    {{#sortable-item}}
  {{/each}}
{{/sortable}}
```

If you think about components in terms of existing HTML elements you can see that it kind of looks a little bit like a `select` which has `options` inside. To make this work it's likely that the `sortable-items` would need to communicate with the sortable list. One option is to use `parentView` in your component to get access to the parent.

[Take a look at this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVTXJyyBxQc) from Ryan Florence to get more ideas about how to deal with composable components.

### Update

Updated my answer to include an each around `{{sortable-item}}` to change the context.

Reading through the [Ember each helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/each.js) it seems that it would be possible for a component to do what you want but it looks really hairy.

Comment: So I feared - I actually was just in that thread for a similar issue a few days ago. Would really like to see this land in Ember someday!

Comment: Wouldn't `{{title}}` in the block component in your example still access the controller property, not the component property?